# Deploy application on Amazon AWS using BeanStalk API and LoadBalancing API

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to add my application to amazon aws using the Beanstalk API.

I have a few webpages along with a backend in php and database in MYSQL which is called from the webpages using AJAX.

I want to deploy this on Amazon aws using the Beanstalk API and loadbalance it using the LoadBalancing API. I don't seem to find any tutorial online which would help me host my application.

Can someone guide me to how I should go about deploying my application ?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Elastic Beanstalk for PHP is somehow [documented here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP_eb.html).

As for your setup, here are the basic steps:
1. create an RDS instance manually. don't set Elastic Beanstalk do it for you as it poorly manages it. in the Beanstalk setup wizard make sure you use your preset RDS and not let the wizard create one.
2. start the [Elastic Beanstalk wizard](https://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/?region=us-east-1#/newApplication), define it as a web server and ensure the Environment type is `Load Balancing, autoscaling`. This will automatically create the load balancing configuration so don't worry about that.
3. from there I'd recommend continuing with the sample application just to make sure everything is setup correctly.
4. After the application launches and you're able to access it from the web, you should go ahead and `git aws.push` your own application. [some doc here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.html).

A fair warning - Amazon Elastic Beanstalk isn't easy to set up. If you are signed up to their support - use it. a lot :)